# Explanation of a recurrence relation in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the answer to the following question but I am not sure how this answer was solved. I am looking for some help with this explanation, thanks!

> Find the recurrence relation for the number of ways to arrange flags on an $n$-foot flagpole using the three types of flags: red flags $2$ foot high, yellow flags $1$ foot hight and blue flags $1$ foot high

The solution is: $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + a_{n-1}$

My thinking was to consider cases, where it starts with a blue flag, or starts with a yellow flag or starts with a red flag.

And what are the initial conditions of this recurrence relation?

Comment: Well, the top flag is either red, blue or yellow.  If it is red then the remaining arrangement belongs to $a_{n-1}$.  If it is blue or yellow, the remaining arrangement belongs to $a_{n}$.

Comment: why does the remaining arrangements belong to $a_{n-1}$ if the top is red?

Comment: Because the red flag is $2$ feet long so, if the total length is $n+1$ then the other flags must take up $n+1-2=n-1$ feet.

Comment: and then the same explanation for if it is blue or yellow?

Comment: Well, follow the same logic only know the blue (or yellow) flag has length $1$.

Comment: also is this answer equivalent to $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

Comment: Of course.  Though in both cases you have to specify initial conditions as well.

Comment: and what would $a_0, a_1$ be?

Comment: that's my next question

Comment: Please put in some effort of your own.  Note: it isn't clear what $a_0$ even means so you might be better off computing $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as counting the strings with length $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{RR,Y,B\}$.
Let us denote their number as $L_n$. We have $L_1=2$ (strings $Y$ and $B$), $L_2=5$ (strings $YY,BB,YB,BY,RR$) and for any $n\geq 3$
$$ L_{n} = 2 L_{n-1}+L_{n-2} $$
by considering the removal of the first symbol in a string with length $n$. If the first symbol is $RR$ the truncated string is a valid string with length $n-2$, if the first symbol is $Y$ *or* $B$ the truncated string is a valid string with length $n-1$. Conversely, each string with length $n$ can be obtained by pre-pending $RR$ to a string with length $n-2$, or by pre-pending $Y$ or $B$ to a string with length $n-1$.

---

By the generating functions machinery, $L_n$ behaves like $C\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ for large values of $n$.
You are actually dealing with [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number).

Comment: thanks for this explanation, what would $a_1,a_2$ be? I am now trying to solve it

Comment: @mt12345: it is already there. $L_1=2$ and $L_2=5$.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think I understand!

Comment: is there no $a_0$?

Comment: shouldn't $a_0=1$?

Comment: @mt12345: yes, there is a single empty string.

Comment: awesome, thanks for your time!